# Show hide animation don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to realize show hide animation smoothly.

I have example what I want in [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/wjVoZO)

I'll copy everything in my  [**layout**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/RyXGMR) change class names add additional div (with classname `group hide`) like in example add **jQuery** configuration code but  this did not work.

The problem is I think  `on` class.In my case it don't work.It must be add in `group` class when `button click` is triggered.

Please help

```js
// js to the rescue
var b = $('body');
var isToggled = false; // default state
var origTextStr = b.find('button').text();

$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
 
 var t = $(this),
   next = t.nextAll('.group').first(),
   nextObj = t.nextAll('.design_block');
 
 // change text str
 if( !isToggled ) { t.text('Hide more'); } else { t.text(origTextStr); }
 
 // get height of 'next'
 var nextHeight = next.height() + 'px';
 
 // add transform to all 'next'
 if( !isToggled ){
  nextObj.css('transform', 'translateY('+ nextHeight +')');
  next.addClass('on');
  //addClass('on');
  isToggled = true;
 }
 else {
  nextObj.css('transform','translateY(0)');
  next.removeClass('on');
  isToggled = false;
 }
 
});
```

```css
body.on {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.our_works {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.our_works .design_block {
  width: 210px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.our_works .architecture_img {
  width: 210px;
  height: 198px;
}
.our_works .more_posts {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #2a323d;
  padding: 12px 0 13px 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.our_works .more_posts a {
  color: #fff;
}
.our_works .more_posts a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.group {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.group .design_block {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.group .design_block:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.group .design_block:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.group.on .design_block {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  visibility: visible;
}

.design_block {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="our_works">
      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
      </div>


      <!-- hidden blocks -->
    <div class="group hide">
      
      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
      </div>
 </div>
      <button class="more_posts">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your button is in the DOM under your 
`group` element and jquery tries to find the `next` element
just move it above and `on` will be triggered.

Comment: one second I'll check your'e answer

Comment: this did not help =(

Comment: you placed it to high
Here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxoPzE
Should work

Comment: yup work's the class "on"  adding perfectly .But my slides don't show

Comment: Yeah, just checked the jquery 'on' think. Will investigate the css part.

Comment: Ah, the bootstrap 'hide' class does its job perfectly. It always hides it :) Remove that and your slide will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)** jQuery method instead of CSS animation, it's easier and runs smoother. If you are worried about performance, don't use jQuery. The button is in `position:fixed` so it won't be in the way. The layout is toggled so that only one row is displayed at a time. If you wish to change the behavior so that the bottom row is the only row toggled, see the comments in the code, it's a simple one line swap.

### Demo

```js
$(function() {

  $('.btn').on('click', moreLess);

  function moreLess(e) {
    $('.btn').toggleClass('more less');
    $('.row').slideToggle('slow');
    /* Swap the line below with the line above if you want only
    || the bottom row to show/hide
    */ // $('.hide').slideToggle('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
body.on {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.design {
  width: 210px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 210px;
  height: 198px;
}

.more,
.less {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30vw;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(11, 12, 233, 0.5);
  padding: 12px 0 13px 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
  height: 60px
}

.more a,
.less a {
  color: gold;
  font: 900 20px/1 Verdana;
}

.more a:hover,
.less a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn.more a::before {
  content: 'More...'
}

.btn.less a::before {
  content: '...Less'
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
  <section class="row">
    <article class="content">
      <div class="design">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="preview">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
        <div class="preview">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
        <div class="preview">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
      </div>

    </article>
  </section>
  <button class="btn more">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
      </button>
  <section class='row hide'>
    <article class='content'>
      <!-- hidden blocks -->


      <div class="design">
        <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/fairy-tale-houses-23.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design">
        <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/fairy-tale-houses-23.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design">
        <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/fairy-tale-houses-23.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>


      <div class="design">
        <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/fairy-tale-houses-23.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>


      <div class="design">
        <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/fairy-tale-houses-23.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>


    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```